# How can I include and render a html file with tags in Antora?

Tags: antora

Is there a way to include my own HTML in an Antora adoc file?

.index.adoc

```
include::example$test.html[]

[,html]
----
include::example$test.html[]
----
```

.test.html

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

At the moment my test.html file gets imported but the html tags are not recognized.

[image]

Comment: Note: Embedding HTML won't work for non-HTML output formats, like PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following lines of code within the adoc file.

```
++++
include::example$test.html[]
++++
```